# How to turn off update for NVidia Driver from NVIDIA Control Panel?

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce, display-driver

I'm using Windows 8.1, NVidia Geforce GTX 950M, I enjoy the old driver: VGA_nVidia_Win81_64_VER101813538402. It's stable and I want to keep it that way. How can I disable update from NVIDIA Control Panel? I couldn't find the reference option from the menu bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It did take me awhile to look through the menu bar, and I realize it isn't there. It's in **Manage 3D Settings > Global Settings > Manage update...**

[image: Nvidia Update]

So uncheck this box then NVidia won't check for update anymore.

Note that I don't use Windows 10 so I don't know about [the automatic update  NVidia driver issue](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3gj2o3/stop_windows_10_from_updating_nvidia_display/).